# Can't see HDD during install 12.04 on Lenovo U310

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my Lenovo U310 laptop. Despite GParted being able to see my HDD, when I launch the installation, there are no partitions to choose from.

I think this happens because U310 has 2 HDDs (normal and SSD) and maybe  the boot process contains some magic inside.

Can anybody help with it?

**Update 1**

After some experiments, I found that the problem is in Intel Rapid Start Technology (iRST). It uses the SSD drive as cached disk, and the HDD as accelerated. Both drives work in RAID0. That's why Ubuntu installer can't see any table partitions.

To fix it, I disabled (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> while the notebook is loading) the acceleration of the 500GB hard drive and all is fine.

Comment: Is AHCI enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: No, for now. But I have already tried this mode. And also tried another 'Compatible' mode and no results :(

Comment: May be the most easiest way - to completely remove Windows 7, but I want try to save it if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partition tables are unreadable, they need to be GPT format.  I was not able save the OEM install.

This voids your warranty!!

There is bios bug with Intel Rapid start and Lenovo u310.  Disable it in the bios before continuing.  If you erase OEM partitions while bios is in Rapid Start mode, you lose a ability to enter bios setup, probably forever.  It was documented in u300 manual that you could enter the bios while in rapid start mode by using the "One key restore button", but it is conveniently missing from the u310 manual so it's not considered a defect, and it definitely doesnt work.  Boooooo...!!

1. Do clean shutdown for OEM windows and change disk controller to AHCI mode, and change boot order as needed. (raid mode may work, I didn't try it, you may be able to dual boot in raid mode)
2. Boot into live cd Ubuntu (be sure F2 option pops up on post, if not, you're in rapid start mode)
3. Search for "disk" in unity
4. Launch disk manager
5. Rewrite partitions as needed and install Ubuntu.

Known issues:  trackpad unsupported, right click button doesn't work.  Google it, there a fix that removes trackpad options like scrolling and tap click.

Cairo dock OpenGL mode buggy as heck.  No fix that I can find.

Beware rapid start bios issue.  Research it, disable it.  You have been warned.

Comment: Thank You, Jeremy, for this information! Probably, modern times require difficult decisions...

Comment: I disabled the iRST and Changed the RAID to AHCI Mode and now I can see my partitions on the Install Dialog!! Lets c how far it goes...(although I am trying to Install Windows 8 RP...;-)! )