# Install Ubuntu on a partitioned system

Tags: installation, partitioning, lenovo

I'm trying to install Ubuntu along with my existing Windows 8 OS (the computer came with Windows 7 so I'm supposed to have the old BIOS).

The problem is that when I tried installing Ubuntu from a USB drive I didn't have the option to install it alongside Windows,
I've been told that the problem is that I've got 4 partitions and more partitions just can't be added.
[image: Partitions]

These are the partitions I have on my machine, I think I'll try resizing the Windows7_OS partition in order to free some space and delete one of the others partitions.
**The question is which one can be removed safely.**

Other solutions for running Ubuntu will be appreciated as well :)

B.T.W

I'm using a U310 which is supposed to have 32GB SSD storage as well as 500GB HDD Storage

Comment: Looking at that setup, what is on your D: drive? that might be a great place to consider resizing or even deletion (did I mention backing up first?). I should also note that the drive you have in your U310 is a hybrid drive meaning that it uses the 32GB and the 500GB in tandem to move frequently accessed data to the SSD and switching those that haven't to the HDD. I don't think you get much control over how it does though...

Comment: @Mordoc The D: has some files that can be easily transferred, and a Drivers folder that contain what looks like the installation files of the drivers.
Do you think I should delete it?

Comment: I second @Mordoc. Backup and remove D:. Do not format and keep in unallocated so that Ubuntu installation process can find it and create its own sets of partitions `/` and `swap`. But you may have another problem. See: [Can't see HDD during install of 12.04 on Lenovo U310](http://askubuntu.com/questions/164423/cant-see-hdd-during-install-12-04-on-lenovo-u310)

Comment: @user68186 Why don't you submit yours as the answer and I'll upvote it, that is a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be two issues here.

**First,** as you have found out you need to delete 1 of 4 primary partitions to create more (extended) partitions. I second @Mordoc's comment above. Backup and remove D:. Do not format, keep in unallocated so that Ubuntu installation process can find it and create its own sets of partitions `/` and `swap`.

If you want more space for Ubuntu, you can shrink C: and make the unallocated space a bit bigger.

**Second,** The 32GB SSD is used by Windows in such a way that is not compatible with Ubuntu installation. This has been discussed before in another question. See [Can't see HDD during install 12.04 on Lenovo U310](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164423/cant-see-hdd-during-install-12-04-on-lenovo-u310) for a solution to that problem.

See [Is a 40GB SSD practical to use for ' / '](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18919/is-a-40gb-ssd-practical-to-use-for) for some ways of using the SSD and HDD for Ubuntu.

Hope this helps